# ASP .Net Core Razor: Can't return ViewComponent from my PageModel

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I am trying to use Ajax to call a handler in my Razor page that returns the result of a ViewComponent, however when I try the code below, it says:

> Non-invocable member "ViewComponent" cannot be used like a method.

```
public IActionResult OnGetPriceist()
{
    return ViewComponent("PriceList", new { id= 5 });
}
```

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7051 and it says to create an extension. So in the extension I would be able to return ViewComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using MVC, the `Controller` base class includes a `ViewComponent` *method*, which is just a helper method that creates a `ViewComponentResult` for you. This method does not yet exist in the Razor Pages world, where instead you use `PageModel` as the base class.

One option to work around this is to create an extension method on the `PageModel` class, that would look something like this:

```
public static class PageModelExtensions
{
    public static ViewComponentResult ViewComponent(this PageModel pageModel, string componentName, object arguments)
    {
        return new ViewComponentResult
        {
            ViewComponentName = componentName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            ViewData = pageModel.ViewData,
            TempData = pageModel.TempData
        };
    }
}
```

Apart from it being an extension method, the code above is just [ripped out of `Controller`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L253). In order to use it, you can call it from your existing `OnGetPriceList` (typo fixed) method, like this:

```
public IActionResult OnGetPriceList()
{
    return this.ViewComponent("PriceList", new { id = 5 });
}
```

The key to making it work here is to use `this`, which will resolve it to the extension method, rather than trying to invoke the constructor as a method.

If you're only going to use this *once*, you could forego the extension method and just embed the code itself inside of your handler. That's entirely up to you - some people might prefer the extension method for the whole separation-of-concerns argument.